# Многие ко многим. MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

В базе есть таблицы product, product_category, category.
В product_category две колонки product_id и category_id
Задача получить все товары и чтобы у каждого товара был массив категорий.

Пытаюсь достать в модели так, но получаю дублирование товаров, т.к. у них несколько категорий:

```
class Product
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = DB::instance();
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT product.id, product.name, product.price, product_category.category_id 
                FROM product, product_category 
                WHERE product_category.product_id = product.id";
        return $this->pdo->query($sql);
    }

    public function lastInsertId()
    {
        return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

Получаю это дело в контроллере:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $model = new Product();
    $products = $model->findAll();

    render('main/index', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

В PDO пробовал PDO::FETCH_ASSOC и PDO::FETCH_OBJ.
Возможно ли это сделать одним SQL запросом или нужно под каждым товаром еще раз SQL запрос писать?
Может как-то собрать массив категорий у товара можно? Никак не получается!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете после запроса ваш массив переложить в нужный формат. Одним запросом в любом случае не получится, ведь от дублирования никак не избавиться

Comment: Делаете свой запрос. Получаете двумерный массив целиком. Потом обрабатываете его: товары на верхний уровень массива, категории - в атрибуты товара. И уже этот массив возвращаете из функции. Если вам подойдут категории как строка, то можно сконкатенировать категории в строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню ответ Максима. Упростить можно:

```
public function findAllWithCategory() {
    $products = $this->findAll();
   
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        
        if (!array_key_exists($product['id'], $tree)) {
            $tree[$product['id']] = array_intersect_key($product, array_flip(['id', 'name', 'price']));
        }
        
        $tree[$product['id']]['category'][] = array_intersect_key($product, array_flip(['category_id']));
    }
    
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это гораздо лучше)

Answer (score 1):

Решил пока так:

```
public function findAll()
{
    $sql = "SELECT product.id, product.name, product.price, 
                   product_category.category_id 
            FROM product, product_category 
            WHERE product_category.product_id = product.id";
    return $this->pdo->query($sql);
}

public function findAllWithCategory() {
    $products = $this->findAll();
    $id = $products[0]['id'];
    $tree[$id]['id'] = $products[0]['id'];
    $tree[$id]['name'] = $products[0]['name'];
    $tree[$id]['price'] = $products[0]['price'];
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($product['id'] == $id) {
            $tree[$product['id']]['category'][] = $product['category_id'];
        } else {
            $tree[$product['id']]['id'] = $product['id'];
            $tree[$product['id']]['name'] = $product['name'];
            $tree[$product['id']]['price'] = $product['price'];
            $tree[$product['id']]['category'][] = $product['category_id'];
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Выглядит массивно) Может есть возможность короче?